# The Result of the Roll

Tags: javascript

can someone explain this to me? I don't understand about javascript think, so i will put the formula here. Thanks

```html
Two strings are created :
STRING1 = "[NONCE]:[SERVER SEED]:[NONCE]"
STRING2 = "[NONCE]:[CLIENT SEED]:[NONCE]"
For your last roll :
STRING1 = "232:90ae772c1cae8be4e4489f3fc63808e8e114cadcdf9b0a0a85ae6f97179cf395:232"
STRING2 = "232:yqT8rO0uYLvv6CIm:232"
```

Then HMAC-SHA512 is used to hash STRING1 with STRING2 as the secret key, giving us a 128 character hex string.

The first 8 characters of the hex string are taken and converted to a decimal.

This decimal is then divided by 429496.7295 and rounded off to the nearest whole number.

This whole number is used as your roll, with the maximum possible value being 10,000.

Question:

so the result is

892058e2b2d4e314ed2e01d69e143c4d5c13bd5e7813a9f2b0e94cc032eaf0a0

so where is it come and how to calculate it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a programming question? If it is a math problem ask your question at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: yes it was a programming question, i just don't know how the answer is 892058e2b2d4e314ed2e01d69e143c4d5c13bd5e7813a9f2b0e94cc032eaf0a0
after use HMAC-SHA512

Comment: Look at [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) and at [SHA512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) for the algorithm.

Comment: i had tested it, but still the result not 892058e2b2d4e314ed2e01d69e143c4d5c13bd5e7813a9f2b0e94cc032eaf0a0

Comment: You should add your code.